# persist in one controller and flush in another

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, flush, persist

EDIT for google searchers:
It's impossible to persist in one controller and to flush in another one.

I have two controllers, called by ajax. The first one is called when a change occurs in the twig, this is where I persist.

The second one is called when the "save" button is clicked, and that's when I call flush.

Unfortunately, it does not change anything in the database.

Here are my controllers:

```
public function update_accountAction(Request $request)
{   
    Try
    {
        $code = $request->request->get('code'); 
        $name = $request->request->get('name'); 

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $repo = $em->getRepository('NRtworksChartOfAccountsBundle:Accounttree');

        $to_change = new Accounttree();
        $to_change = $repo->findOneByCode($code);

        $to_change->setName($name);
        $to_change->setCode($code);

        $em->persist($to_change);

        $response = array("code" => 100, "success" => true, "modified" => $code);
        return new Response(json_encode($response));
    }
    Catch(Exception $e)
    {
        $response = array("code" => 100, "success" => false, "error" => $e);
        return new Response($response);
    }

}
```

The next one:

```
public function save_changesAction()
{
     Try
     {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->flush();
        $response = array("code" => 100, "success" => true);
        return new Response(json_encode($response));
     }
     Catch(Exception $e)
     {
        $response = array("code" => 100, "success" => false, "error" => $e);
        return new Response($response);
     }


    $response = array("code" => 100, "success" => true);
    return new Response(json_encode($response));

}
```

Apparently no errors are occurring but no change is done..

I was thinking the problem is that the entity manager is limited to one controller but I did not succeed in call it outside...

Help ?

ps: I have a test controller in which I do persist and flush and the change is done in the DB.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`persist()` calls aren't remembered between requests.

Therefore you can't call `persist()` in one request and `flush()` in a subsequent request.

You will need to implement a caching logic (i.e. saving the entities marked for persistence in the session) to make this work.

Comment: that's what I thought. I'll try with the sessions later tonight. Thanks